# Host resources management - vSphere Client

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, filesystems, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I'm using vSphere Client version 6.7, having 2 hosts in a cluster.
i want to know before i'm entering one host into maintenance mode, if the other host will be able to hold both servers resources.
yes i know, i could calculate it by using free/used space in CPU,Storage,Memory fields.
i want to know if there is a simulator or something like that that will show me what will be the situation after i will move all VMs to the other host.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While there are simulators, they are most probably not very useful since this depends heavily on the workload of your VMs. It's next to impossible to predict this kind of thing accurately, especially without having actual usage data.

Just do it, preferably at a time of low usage. The worst thing that can happen is that the VMs are a little slower during the time of maintenance. It could be helpful to announce the maintenance window to you users beforehand.