# VMware - cluster resources utilization

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, cluster, vmware-vsphere

I have 2 hosts in a cluster (running vSphere Client version 6.7).
how can i be sure that when i want to enter one of them into maintenance mode, the other one would be able to hold all VM's resources?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Define 'hold' please, hold as in the VMs will run, or hold as in they'll bee completely uncontended? something else?

Comment: Hold as all the VMs will run

Comment: That's basically the same question [you asked before](https://serverfault.com/questions/1028764/host-resources-management-vsphere-client). It would have been better to expand your question instead of asking it again, if the previous answer wasn't satisfactory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, the function you need to enable and configure to do this is called 'admission control' within the HA service. Basically it'll stop you adding in more VM resources than the cluster could handle in the event of a certain number of host failures.

Comment: There are some pros and cons on using Admission Control. However, it is the thing OP wants to do. Before starting using it, I would recommend to read and understand how it works. Useful links: 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/vsphere-6-5-ha-drs-improvements-part-i
http://vmnomad.blogspot.com/2016/04/why-i-prefer-to-disable-vsphere-ha.html